# Call WebApi method using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a WebApi project that get firstname and lastname as a input parameter and return all the info. I use RestShop to call the webApi and return data. This is working and is returning but for some reason I have to use Ajax call to call the api. I can’t get the Ajax call working. I have used different links in this website but it return me empty data and error. it retuen empty for both alerts:  alert(FirstName); and at the end retues [object][object] error.

This is the RestShop that is working:

```
 public List<Data> GetData(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        RestClient _client = new RestClient();
        string _url = "http://localhost:51142";
        _client = new RestClient(_url);


        //DocGen/Documents/GetByFLName/TERRI/TIMMERMAN
        var request = new RestRequest("Gen/Doc/GetByFLName/{FirstName}/{LastName}", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddParameter("FirstName", FirstName, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.AddParameter("LastName", LastName, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        var response = _client.Execute<List<Data>>(request);
        if (response.Data == null)
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);

        return response.Data;

    }
```

This is Ajax code to call same method ans it returns , [object][object] error.

```
function GetEmployee() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    alert(FirstName);
    var LastName = $('#LastName').val();
    alert(LastName);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:51142/Gen/Doc/GetByFLName/'+ '/' + FirstName + LastName,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is textboxes:

```
First Name:
   @Html.TextBox("FirstName")

  Last Name:
  @Html.TextBox("LastName")
```

and this is my method in webApi:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetByFLName(string id1, string id2)
    {

        DAL.DataManager dal = new DAL.DataManager();
        CMSIGateway gateway = new CMSIGateway();
        gateway = dal.Get_CM_BY_FLName(id1, id2);


        if (gateway == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(gateway);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't just the slash missing between the two parameters in the ajax request?

Comment: If it's a different port than requesting page you need to enable cors in the api. What errors are you seeing? What is request status when you inspect it in dev tools network?

Comment: @PanayotTodorov thanks I changed it but same, I am getting error.  also   alert(FirstName); and alert(LastName); are empty too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ur putting incorrect parameter to the url it should be like this

```
 url: 'http://localhost:51142/Gen/Doc/GetByFLName?id1=' + FirstName + "&id2=" +LastName
```